# When trying to install JWT package for Django getting error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: django, installation, jwt

I was working on django project where i had received an error

```html
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware erp.middleware: "No module named jwt"
```

So that i tried to install jwt package by typing

```html
pip install jwt
```

which leads to an error

```html
 build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:3551:13: warning: ‘_ssl_thread_locking_function’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static void _ssl_thread_locking_function(int mode, int n, const char *file,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of cryptography
Command "/home/charles/.virtualenvs/virtualenvpython/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-hU6Fxe/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-h5K4aB/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/charles/.virtualenvs/virtualenvpython/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-hU6Fxe/cryptography/
```

i dont what issue is going on please help me to solve this issue 
i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS
python 2.7.15rc1
django 1.3.7

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt install python-dev libffi-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

I will suggest that use the latest version of python and Django.

Comment: hmmm ...i found the issue was i wrongly typed jwt package name as `pip install jwt` but it was `pip install PyJWT`

Comment: Add your fix. These may help other developers.